# How start a process after another one is done in SimPy?

Tags: python, process, synchronization, simpy

I am working on a assignment and I have to use SimPy for it. Basically there is an algorithm I have to implement and this algorithm consists of two procedures (basically two different functions). After first procedure is completed, second one has to start. I couldn't find a way to do it?

```
import random
import networkx as nx
from distsim import * 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Alg1(Node):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        Node.__init__(self, *args)
        self.dist = 0
        self.dists = {}
        self.all_dists = {}
        self.time_stamp_one = 0
        self.vel = 10
        self.procedure_1_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_1())
        self.procedure_2_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_2())
        
        
        
    def procedure_1(self):
        *This function includes procedure_1's operations
        *This one has to start first and shouldn't be interrupted until its done
                      
    def procedure_2(self):
        *This function includes procedure_2's operations
        *After procedure_1 is completed, this function will take the rest
```

I have tried to use env.timeout() function inside procedure_2 for a sufficient time to procedure_1 complete however it didn't work and procedure_2 interrupted in every iteration.

Based on @Michael's advice I've made the change below:

```py
    def run(self):
       print("------RUN1--------")
       self.procedure_1_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_1())
       yield self.env.process(self.procedure_1())
       print("------RUN2--------")
       self.procedure_2_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_2())
       yield self.env.process(self.procedure_2())
```

Basically I am creating and yielding processes sequentially. But in this case, procedure_1 starts and works correctly but after it procedure_2 doesn't start. Why is that happening?

Below shows the programs output. It seems that before procedure_1() starts, it enters run() 4 times but never moves on after the first yield.

```
------RUN1--------
------RUN1--------
------RUN1--------
------RUN1--------
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
0: TIMEOUT received from 0 at time 2
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
0: TIMEOUT received from 0 at time 2
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
1: PROBE received from 0 at time 3
{0: 10.0}
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
1: PROBE received from 0 at time 3
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
0: REPLY received from 1 at time 4
{1: 10.0}
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
0: PROBE received from 1 at time 4
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
2: PROBE received from 1 at time 4
{1: 10.0}
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
1: REPLY received from 2 at time 5
{0: 10.0, 2: 10.0}
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
1: PROBE received from 2 at time 5
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
3: PROBE received from 2 at time 5
{2: 10.0}
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
2: REPLY received from 3 at time 6
{1: 10.0, 3: 10.0}
----------PROCEDURE1--------------
2: PROBE received from 3 at time 6
```

Comment: add a  yield self.procedure_1_proc  right after you create procedure_1 and before you create procedure_2.

  When you yield, your procedure waits for the called procedure to complete, just like a function call.

Comment: using Google to find `simpy self.env.process` I found [Process Interaction — SimPy 4.1.1 documentation](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpy_intro/process_interaction.html) and it shows example code which uses `yield` and comment in code explains it (as @Michael already explained it).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def run(self):
       print("------RUN1--------")
       procedure_1_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_1())
       yield procedure_1_proc
       print("------RUN2--------")
       procedure_2_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_2())
       yield procedure_2_proc
```

also drop these lines in `__init__()`

```
self.procedure_1_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_1())
self.procedure_2_proc = self.env.process(self.procedure_2())
```

If this does not work, you may have other issues with your code.  Can you post a full example of your code. How are you calling run()?